# Where the Modules configuration interface go in Project Structure - Intellij IDEA (2016.3.3)?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Recently I am study java with IntelliJ, and when I follow the steps to config Modules:

This is tutorial:

[image]

This is the IntelliJ I am using, in the Project Settings:

[image]

So, how can I config the Module in the  Intellij IDEA (2016.3.3)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you opened/created the project incorrectly.
Try opening an existing module `File` -> `New` -> `Module From Existing Sources...`
or adding a new module `File` -> `New` -> `Module`
And then check the project structure again.

[image]